# Nothing happens when doing "mina setup"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, mina

I'm trying to set up Mina for deploying my Rails app. Unfortunately, when running `mina setup` or `mina deploy`, I get to the password prompt, and then nothing happens anymore.

I can manually ssh with the given user and password, so this shouldn't be a problem. But I have no idea, where mina's stuck:

```
  josh@macbuech:~/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/base (features/deployment *)$ mina deploy --verbose
  base@josh.ch's password: 


  -----> Mina: SIGINT received.
         Elapsed time: 61.00 seconds
```

Interestingly, yesterday it was suddenly able to connect (one of a dozen retries worded, I guess):

```
josh@macbuech:~/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/base (features/deployment *)$ mina deploy --verbose
base@josh.ch's password: 
       stdin: is not a tty  
       jailshell: line 3: cd: /var/www/base.josh.ch: No such file or directory
 !     ERROR: not set up.
       The path '/var/www/base.josh.ch' is not accessible on the server. 
       You may need to run 'mina setup' first. 

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 15
```

Then, I couldn't connect to my server anymore (neither by using mina nor plain ssh). I had to call support, and they did something that re-enabled ssh for me. Mina still doesn't work.

In `config/deploy.rb`, I only added `set :user ...` and changed `:domain`, `:deploy_to` and `:repository`.

```
set :domain, 'josh.ch'
set :user, 'base'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/base.josh.ch"
set :repository, 'git://jmuheim/base'
set :branch, 'master'
```

Any idea? I'd rather not switch back to Capistrano... Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an old question but this is for any future Googlers that stumble across this. I had the issue described in the question, mina hanging after password entry. Looking around in the issues section of the mina git repo lead me to [the fix](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/99), albeit a silly one.

In your deploy.rb file put this setting:

```
set :term_mode, nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried run:

```
mina init
```

after install gem?

Can you show your deploy.rb?

Comment: Ok, i think you should manually create folder /var/www/base.josh.ch on remote server and set permissions for base user: chown -R /var/www/base.josh.ch

Comment: As long as I can't connect, this is useless. I finally added my public key to the server's known hosts, and this works. Very strange that password authentication doesn't, though.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck with password authentication. But with public key SSH authentication, it's working fine.

HOW TO: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password